# Doctrine Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 's.features' in 'field list''

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, mysql-error-1054

I added a new column "features" to the site table and regenerated the models using Doctrine.
This code is causing an error:

```
 $siteTable = Doctrine_Core::getTable("Site");
 $site = $siteTable->findOneByName("site"); // this line is throwing an exception
```

Exception:

> Unknown column "s.features" in field list.....

I checked the database and it contains the field, I also checked the Site model and the table definition contains the column information. The primary key of all tables is `id`.
Also in the line which throws the exception I am not using the newly added column. If I remove the column from the table definition of the site object then the above code works...

This error is happening to any table when I add a new column and regenerate the models from it.

Comment: Have you checked the database has the column? Sounds like you haven't rebuilt the database.

Comment: Could your post your model (schema.yml for instance) and your SQL DB schema?

Comment: If you really want to get this answered please post.

The output of `DESCRIBE site;` from database.
Your schema.yml file.
And the BaseSite comment block from the top of your generated/BaseSite.php file

Comment: I haven't used Doctrine with Zend Framework, but what can sometimes happen with Symfony is that doctrine generates two versions of your model files (in my experience this is often the result of rebuilding your database on different computers when one has APC installed and the other doesn't)

PHP on the command line usually uses a different php.ini file to Apache so the Model files generated on the command line aren't always the same ones that are autoloaded by Doctrine in your website. 

Anyway, that is a possible cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Do you checked the  generated Base Table Classes ? Should be `BaseSite.class.php`

```
./doctrine build-all
```

should fix the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

check this command out
goto doctrine directory
there must be **bin/** and **Doctrine/** directories there

```
php bin/doctrine orm:generate-proxies
```