# Doctrine fails on update query

Tags: sql, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I get this error:

> 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'domain_name'
>   in 'where clause'

when I try to execute this query:

```
public function updateDomain($domain_name, $expiration_date, $authcode)
{
     $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('domain d')
        ->set('d.domain_name', '?', $domain_name)
        ->set('d.expiration_date', '?', $expiration_date)
        ->set('d.authcode', '?', $authcode)
        ->where('d.domain_name = ?', $domain_name)
        ->execute();
}
```

Here is a diagram of my database:

> id | client_id | registar_id | domain_name | expiration_date |
>   authcode ....

`id` is the primary key.

`client_id` and `registar_id` are foreign keys.

More, when I execute the query generated by Doctrine in my database, it works fine...

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262223/doctrine-column-not-found-1054-unknown-column-s-features-in-field-list (hopefully some of the answers may help you)

Comment: no answer has helped me...

Comment: Run `php symfony doctrine:build --all-classes`

Answer (score 2):

I have find the issue:

```
update('Domain d')
```

The first letter of the table name must be in capital letter....

Comment: +1 good that you followed up. This may help others in the future

Comment: Because it's not the table name but the name of your model class.